# How to select and copy upto Last cell when uneven Dynamic data's with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, select, dynamic

```
input:

45311       
0003ML00030-1   0003ML00030-2   0003ML00030-3
0003ML00030-1   0003ML00030-1
```

[image: See my snap highlighted area need to select]

See my snap highlighted area need to select, Last cell some times Blank and Also dynamic.

From the Above input, need to select All data and copy it. 
When i reuse the sheet The Data Range may vary, at the time standard formula not working properly.

Currently i use this VBA code.

```
Sub Macro()
 Sheets("input").Select
Range("D2").Select
   Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
   Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

When i use this code it select Extreme last cell (row 1048570 x col 41).

But in this case Last cell is (row4 x col7)
like this way i need to select Dynamically if Data range vary

Comment: Look [at this accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vbahttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: But this marked answer- shows last Rows related details only. Any way thanks for your comment

Comment: You can apply similar logic to finding the last column

Comment: Sorry i have no idea, today fully tried many times, not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro()
Sheets("input").Activate
Range("b1").CurrentRegion.Copy

End Sub
```

Usually, to check the last cell's row No. you can use

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

to check the last cell's column No. you can use

```
Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

---

### Here is the revised code and picture's demo.

```
Sub Macro()
Sheets("input").Activate
Set rng = Range("d1").CurrentRegion
rng.Offset(1, 3).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count - 3).Copy

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Its select from HOME cell A1, But my source data start from D2

Comment: I will use `Range("D2: F" & r).Copy`, and let `r = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row`, eg. assuming your data region end in col F.  It is better to give a picture of your screen.

Comment: But Col F is not fixed one. its dynamic

Comment: last column `Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: i am not understand. could you please update macro in answer field.

Comment: Please check the above revised macro code with the usage of `offset`. If it works please take it as answer.@baskar

Comment: This code select full Active region, with offset . But i need to skip the unwanted column.  Because as per your snap Column A:C no data, in my case Col A:C all filled with data. So this is not match with my requirement.

Comment: [See the current output as per your code](https://ibb.co/84r5sCQ)

Comment: you should change it to 'rng.Offset(1, 3).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count -3).Copy'  .It's better to paste the screen capture at the beginning, It will show us your data structure.

Comment: Wow its perfectly works, kindly update it to Answer Field. i accept this as my answer...